# Kubectl using command to get cluster status

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I need to create a shell-script which examine the cluster
Status.**

I saw that the `kubectl describe-nodes` provides lots of data
I can output it to json and then parse it but maybe it’s just overkill.
Is there a simple way to with `kubectl` command to get the status of the cluster ? just if its up / down

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The least expensive way to check if you can reach the API server is `kubectl version`. In addition `kubectl cluster-info` gives you some more info.

Comment: another one is `kubectl get componentstatus`

Comment: `kubectl get componentstatus` depricated.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Michael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54882812/3772478), that would only tell you about the API server or master and internal services like KubeDns etc, but not the nodes.

It depends on your need and definition of "status" here. You could run `kubectl cluster-info` followed by `kubectl get nodes` and check the `STATUS` column for all nodes using parsing tools like `awk`, `jq` or kubectl's own `-o jsonpath` option to verify that all nodes are ready.

Answer (score 3):

The below command would display the health of scheduler, controller and `etcd`

`kubectl get cs`

Command below lists Kubernetes core components like, `etcd`, controller, scheduler, kube-proxy, core-dns, network plugin. All those pods should be running to be sure that Kubernetes is healthy.

`kubectl get pod -n kube-system`

Finally deploy one front-end and back-end Pod and verify the inter-pod communication to ensure that cluster is up and working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the commands to get cluster status based on requirements:

- To get information regarding where your Kubernetes master is running at, CoreDNS is running at, kubernetes-dasboard is running at, use 
  `kubectl cluster-info`
- To get detailed information to further debug and diagnose cluster problem, use `kubectl cluster-info dump`
- To get only the health status for your node use, `kubectl get componentstatus` or `kubectl get cs`

*To show detailed information about a resource use `kubectl describe node <node>`